# Toggle 2 div with one onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 divs which i need to toggle them with one button, the first one slide Up and the second one slide down.

HTML
    dasdasdasdasd

```
<button>Toggle 'em</button>
```

JQuery

```
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  $( "#nav" ).slideUp();
});
```

Can anybody help me out?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sm6e28q4/5/)

Comment: Because of the hash before **nav**, jQuery is just searching for the first element (ID's should be unique). Because of this, just the first element will be hidden in your version. Everything is right with your code, except the hash. **Try using classes where you can!**

Answer (score 2):

You can use `class` instead of `id` and make one `div` hidden by using `display:none;`

html:

```
<div class="nav" style="background:black; width:100%; height:95px">dasdasdasdasd</div>
 <div class="nav" style="background:gray; height:200px;display:none;"></div>

<button>Toggle 'em</button>
```

jquery

```
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  $( ".nav" ).toggle( "slow" );
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sm6e28q4/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

Use a `class` or then `name` attribute instead of an `id` .

**HTML**

```
<div class="nav" style="background:black; width:100%; height:95px">dasdasdasdasd</div>
 <div class="nav" style="background:gray; height:200px"></div>

<button>Toggle 'em</button>
```

**JS**

```
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  $( ".nav" ).toggle( "slow" );
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mfh9x9Lu/)**

**PS**

Never use the same `id` for two elements. An `id` should be unigue.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate ids are invalid html, you should rather use class instead.

You will also need to hide one element in beginning for toggling.:

```
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  $( ".nav" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t6pvfbvu/)**

Comment: Thanks, but i need to both div goes away at the same time, the header goes with slideup and the footer with sliddown. Is it possible?

Comment: @Amir: you can use `slideToggle` instead of `toggle`. see the answer. updated now...

Comment: Could you provide me an example, slidetoggle just applied on one class, and it's not what i need, imagine when you click on the button, both div which i have should goes away from page one from up and one from down, is that make sense to you?

Comment: @Amir: you will need to use animate instead of slideToggle in that case. toggle does not give option to specify directions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hide one element to toggle them differently

```
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  $( "#nav1" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
    $( "#nav2" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sm6e28q4/4/)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `div` has an id of `nav`. In order to select 2 divs, you can try assigning the same **class** name to both, for example:
`<div class="nav"></div>` (x2)

Then change your jQuery to:
`$('.nav').slideUp();`

That way, jQuery knows to select **both** divs and slide them up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**Html**

```
<div id="nav1" style="background:black; width:100%; height:95px">dasdasdasdasd</div>
<div id="nav2" style="background:gray; height:200px"></div>
```

And some **CSS**

```
#nav1{
    display:none;
}
```

**Script**

```
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  $( "#nav1,#nav2" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/sm6e28q4/6/)